# Expected coverage after repeated samples of size $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a set $S$ of $n$ elements, from which I repeatedly sample $m$ elements. Each of the individual samples are without replacement (so $n$ choose $m$), but they all choose from the full set. Given this setup, how many distinct elements of $S$ can I expect to have been picked after $p$ samples?

The specific case of $m=1$ has been answered here before (several times, even), but I haven't been able to find this particular variant, and the generalization to arbitrary $m$ eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that a given element of $S$ is picked in a particular sample
is $m/n$.  The probability it is  picked at least once in $p$ samples is thus $1 - (1 - m/n)^p$.  By additivity of expectation, the expected number of 
distinct elements picked is 
$$n \left(1 - \left(1-\dfrac{m}{n}\right)^p\right)$$

Comment: What is the probability that a given item is selected at least $s$ times where $s<=p$?

Comment: and/or the expected number of times a particular item is selected after $p$ samples? Thanks!

Comment: The number of times the given item is selected in $p$ samples is a binomial random variable with parameters $p$ and $m/n$.